# C# MongoDB.Driver GetServer is Gone, What Now?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

From the mongoDB.Driver docs (http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-csharp-driver/)

> **Get a Reference to a Server Object**
>
> To get a reference to a server object from the client object, write this:
>
> `var server = client.GetServer();`

In the latest release the `GetServer` method is gone, but the doc have not been updated, what do we use now?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`GetServer` is part of the old API.

To use the new, shiny and `async`-ready API simply call `GetDatabase` directly on the client to get an `IMongoDatabase` and `GetCollection` on it to get an `IMongoCollection`:

```
var db = client.GetDatabase("HamsterSchool");
var collection = db.GetCollection<Hamster>("Hamsters");
```

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the quick response. However, before I used to beable to test a connection via `mongoServer.State != MongoServerState.Connected`, now what can I do? Try to get a known database and check if what is returned is non-null?

Comment: Also, `IMongoQuery` and `Query` have gone, do you know where to?

Comment: @Killercam you can use `Mongoclient.ListDatabasesAsync` to make sure you're able to reach the server.

Comment: @Killercam Use the `Builders` class.

Comment: But not all permissions allow to list databases, or am I wrong there? I also assume that the `Query` stuff has now been replaced with the fluent syntax `var names = await db.GetCollection<Person>("people")
    .Find(x => x.FirstName == "Jack")
    .SortBy(x => x.Age)
    .Project(x => x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName)
    .ToListAsync();` etc.

Comment: @Killercam That is more of a replacement for Linq. Query is what you used instead of the lambda expressions.

Comment: @Killercam I don't think there's any docs other than this post: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-20-net-driver

Comment: @Killercam take a look at this for checking for a connection: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29459990/885318