# ArgumentException: Invalid keyword 'mongodb+srv://test:test@HOST' in MongoDB + Unity2D - Live MongoDB not connecting

Tags: c#, mongodb, unity-game-engine, amazon-ec2

I am trying to connect my Live MongoDB Database in local, but getting error while I use external string instead of `localhost`

I use :

- MongoDB database v4.0.x (used FREE Cluster of mongoDB)
- Unity 2020.3.13

If I use **localhost**, This code works fine even all insert, Update, Delete queries works perfect

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using MongoDB.Driver.Builders;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json ;

public class Login_Screen : MonoBehaviour {

public InputField usernameedit;
public InputField passwordone;
public Button loginButton;


  void start(){
    string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
    var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
    var server = client.GetServer();
    var database = server.GetDatabase("admin");
    var playercollection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("users");
  }
}
```

But Same thing I use for **LIVE** database calling, then causing below error. not even connect.

```
string connectionString = "mongodb+srv://testUsername:testPassword@testClustor.mongodb.net?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
```

Error message is below :

`ArgumentException: Invalid keyword 'mongodb+srv://testusername:testpassword@xyz.xxx.mongodb.net/admin1?w'. MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item (System.String keyword, System.Object value) (at <6da29fc855c44d33ad78b3e27475ff27>:0) System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString (System.String value) (at <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0) MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionStringBuilder..ctor (System.String connectionString) (at <6da29fc855c44d33ad78b3e27475ff27>:0) MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.ParseConnectionString (System.String connectionString) (at <6da29fc855c44d33ad78b3e27475ff27>:0) MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient..ctor (System.String connectionString) (at <6da29fc855c44d33ad78b3e27475ff27>:0) Login_Screen.DoLogin () (at Assets/Script/Login_Screen.cs:61) UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () (at <24599fe2776145d58ab771516c063d56>:0) UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at <24599fe2776145d58ab771516c063d56>:0) UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/UI/Core/Button.cs:68) UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/UI/Core/Button.cs:110) UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:50) UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction1[T1] functor) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:262) UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update() (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:385)`

[image]

I really wasted 2 days of finding solution, Please help me anybody. Thanks in advance

Comment: mongodb+srv ?? Surely the +srv is what its moaning about

Comment: @BugFinder, It's in generated by cloud.mongodb.com : MongoDB Official Cluster panel. They give whole string for this

Comment: [Please consider including important error information such as tracebacks as text in questions, rather than only including them in images](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) - See the link for more information about why that is helpful.  This question would also be improved by mentioning what version of the driver you are using, where you got it, etc.

Comment: @Ruzihm, I had updated Error logs along with Screenshot.

Comment: Thanks - Is the driver you are using the 2.13 one available [here on the mongodb website](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/csharp/) or [on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/mongodb.driver) or is it some other version?

Comment: Driver means what? MongoDB driver is directly installed latest from Nuget.

Comment: Okay, I tried to reproduce the behavior here and I can't use `GetServer` because that isn't defined in Mo ngoClient in version 2.13. Trying to figure out how you used this method, and I googled "mongoclient getserver unity" and it results in documentation for driver version 1.11.  Anyway, please include the version of the mongodb driver you are using because for me getting "latest from nuget" version of mongodb gives me version 2.13 which would give you a CS1061 error on the `client.GetServer();` at compile time and the question does not describe that.

Comment: The long error text you have added since i was last here shows a different error to the picture of an error. As now it talks of Admin1 not admin and instead of retrywrites the first letter is w.. you arent making it easy for people

Comment: I can only guess that asker is using an old version of the mongo db driver and that using a newer version of the mongodb driver such as 2.13, then some different method calls would fix this problem. But, it's hard to be sure because the question isn't enough to help potential answerers reproduce the problem.  Voting to close until a [mre] is included.

Comment: @BugFinder, actually I had make more than 1 database, admin and admin1 I thought if `admin` is system defined, then created new database `admin1` and tried, but got same error.

Comment: If admin was system defined it would have happened on your local machine. Thing is. Its not the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Check the settings of your db, and of your db user - make sure they are reachable from external IPs.

I modified my connection string like this:

```
 private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _config = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"dbUser", "xxxxxx"},
            {"dbName", "YourDbName"},
            {"password", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
        };

        public IMongoDatabase CreateInstance()
        {
            var client = new MongoClient($"mongodb+srv://{_config["dbUser"]}:{HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_config["password"])}@pocdata.0u29g.mongodb.net/{HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_config["dbName"])}?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
            return client.GetDatabase(_config["dbName"]);
        }
```

I just use the public method for connecting to db, but this is not mandatory - you can replace the values directly - just url encode the password and db name