# C# MongoDB.Driver - How to form a constructor

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, rest, mongodb-.net-driver

I am currently following an online tutorial to create a RESTful API for MongoDB. The guide includes a DataAccess class for CRUD functionality. It is using the old MongoDB API which is now deprecated.There are three variables for Client, Server and Database and then has a constructor for the class:

```
MongoClient _client;
MongoServer _server;
MongoDatabase _db;

public DataAccess()
{
    _client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    _server = _client.GetServer();
    _db = _server.GetDatabase("EmployeeDB");      
}
```

The new API does not need the server variable so you just call directly on the client ([C# MongoDB.Driver GetServer is Gone, What Now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457098/c-sharp-mongodb-driver-getserver-is-gone-what-now))  but I'm having trouble with the constructor. This is what I have but is throwing a "Cannot implicitly convert type" error for the _db line of code in the constructor:

```
MongoClient _client;
MongoDatabase _db;

public DataAccess()
{
    _client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    _db = _client.GetDatabase("Users");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MongoClient.GetDatabase`  returns `IMongoDatabase` interface.

Change your code to:

```
MongoClient _client;
IMongoDatabase _db;

public DataAccess()
{
    _client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    _db = _client.GetDatabase("Users");
}
```

Comment: The constructor no longer has as any errors. It does now mean that the methods for the class have errors. For example this method :

      `public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
         {
             return _db.GetCollection<User>("Users").FindAll();
         }`

The error is "IMongoCollection<User> does not contain a definition and no extenstion method FindAll accepting a first arguement of type iMongoCollection<User> could not be found"

Comment: Instead of findall you could use .Find(x=>true).ToEnumerable()