# MongoDB C# Connection : client doesnt have a function .GetServer()

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using MongoDB C# Driver 2.10 with MongoDB v4.2 and I want to test if connection is successful.

Most People say that i should do the following:

```
var client = new MongoClient("ConnectionString");

db = client.GetDatabase(database);
var server = client.GetServer();
try
{
    server.Ping();
    Console.WriteLine("Connected"); 
}
catch (ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed");
}
```

But Actually My Program says that client doesnt have a function .GetServer().

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Function `GetServer()` was deprecated and is now removed, see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-664

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit So how can i check the connection in the lastest versions ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# MongoDB.Driver GetServer is Gone, What Now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457098/c-sharp-mongodb-driver-getserver-is-gone-what-now)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I am not that good in async programming so is there another way without using async programming ?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Is it just enough to use try-catch statements to know if the insert-update-delete operation succeeded ?

Comment: Sorry, I never used the C# driver yet, I cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to check to see if you're connected to a MongoDB server (either local or remote is to use the following API code  (this can also be done using a console app or mvc project as well):

Create the following Classes, and modify the following

**Controller**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using {{YourApplicationName}}.Repository;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class YourControllerName : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IRepository _repo;

    [HttpGet, Route("CheckConnection")]

        public async Task<IActionResult> CheckConnection()
        {
            var result = await _repo.CheckConnection();
            if (result == null || result.Count <= 0)
                return BadRequest("Failed to connect to database.");
            return Ok("Database connection was successful");
        }
```

**IRepository**

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public interface IRepository
{
    Task<List<BsonDocument>> CheckConnection();
}
```

**Repository**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private readonly MongoClient _client;
    private readonly IMongoDatabase _database;

    public async Task<List<BsonDocument>> CheckConnection()
    {
        List<BsonDocument> list = await _database.ListCollections().ToListAsync();
        var populatedList = (list != null && list.Count > 0) ? list : null;
        return populatedList;
    }
}
```

**appSettings.json**

Add this to your file

```
"DatabaseSettings": {
    "ConnectionString": "Your Server Connection String"
}
```

**Database Settings.cs**

```
public class DatabaseSettings
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; } 
}
```

**Startup.cs**

Add this line to the Configure Services Method

```
services.AddSingleton(sp =>
            sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<DatabaseSettings>>().Value);
```

Make sure you create at least one DB, along with at least one collection.

Run the application in debug mode and call the method using Postman, and you should get your list of collections back. If so, then your DB connection was successful. If not, check your connection string.